# Get property value in JavaScript with script mediator

Tags: javascript, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Is there a way, inside the javascript code from WSO2 ESB's Script mediator, to get a property's value when this property has a scope different from "default"  ?

**In case of a property with default scope :**

```
get-property('MyProperty')
```

OR

```
<script language="js">
   mc.getProperty("MyProperty");
</script>
```

**In case of a property with 'transport' scope :**

```
get-property('transport','FILE_NAME')
```

OR

```
<script language="js">
   mc.????????
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that you can not get properties using mc.get-property()

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can not get properties of other scopes than synapse using

> mc.get-property("Property Name")

since mc is instance of Synapse.MessageContext in order to get other message context properties I do something like this in java, I don't know that if it is applicable in javascript or not. I do this for axis2 message context properties.
Here "context" is the instance of Synapse.MessageContext.

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext;
            axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext)context).getAxis2MessageContext();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get property using this code:

```
<property name="ComingRoles" expression="your property or value" scope="default"  />
<script language="js">var rolelist = mc.getProperty('ComingRoles');</script>
```

I test it with WSO2ESB 4.9.0

**Update**:

If your property is not define in default scope, first you must define it in default scope.

for example:

```
<property name="authheader" expression="get-property('transport','X-JWT-Assertion')"></property>
<script language="js"> var temp_auth = mc.getProperty('authheader')
</script>
```

It should works with ESB 4.5.0 and above

Comment: when this property has a scope different from "default" ?

Comment: I test it with default scope. I think it's work with other scope. If not, define it in default scope. See this: http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-retrive-property-and.html

Comment: I found an article that get property from transfer scope. The author defines property in default scope. You can see this link:http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/07/use-of-json-web-tokens-in-an-api-fa%C3%A7ade-pattern/. I updated my answer with this fact. your question in very useful. please inform me if this answer is true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `mc` have `get-property` method.
Script Mediator use the Apache `Bean Scripting Framework` for scripting language support. And the `mc` variable represents an implementation of the `MessageContext`, named `ScriptMessageContext.java`.

[Here is the Class of `ScriptMessageContext`][1]

[1]: https://synapse.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/synapse/mediators/bsf/ScriptMessageContext.html 
 You can check any DEFAULT scope property(method) in there.

If not, you may need to put these scope property in custom property.
Like:

```
<property name="CustomAction" expression="get-property('Action')"/>
```

Then use the getProperty("CustomAction") in JS to get them.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like below

```
 <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="JSONPayload"
      scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var pl_string = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload");
                    var newPayload="{\"event\": " + pl_string + "}";
                    mc.setPayloadJSON(newPayload);]]></script>
```