# How to get HTTP headers in Javascript mediator in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am developing a template in WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) which has Script mediator inline.

How can I get headers (HTTP) in this case?

For example, something like:

```
mc.getProperty("$trp")
```

I searched in WSO2 documentation but I did not found anything.

Comment: There are 2 types of heades, http headers and soap header. Which one do you need? (ps. $trp - means transport in this case http)

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Header+Mediator ?

Comment: In this case, I need $trp (http header).

Comment: Copy header value to variable and then manipulate with it

Comment: @simar yes, but I would like to manipulate using javascript, if it is possible... 
Currently, I do that, using xml property.

Comment: According to documention of Script mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Script+Mediator you can't. Only you can add another soap header

Comment: Try something mc.getProperty("$trp:Location") to get location header and check does is work or not.

Comment: Thanks @simar, I think in javascript only handle a Synapse message and http header is not there.

Comment: I have no chance to check it right now.

Comment: I read that in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23080689/4436650